# ETCD OOM a few days later

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

We found our memory usage of etcd is gradually down. But number of bytes used for go gc is gradually up.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/33391637/126043767-872c9f5a-8e5c-41bc-bc21-c7dda44e486c.png

It's will be OOM a few days later.

Just don't know why what's happened.
What do you think of about it above?
Do I need to provide more metrics information?

=============================
Here is the info:

```
etcd Version: 3.3.0
Git SHA: c236067
Go Version: go1.9.3
Go OS/Arch: linux/amd64
```

Part of configuration

```
ETCD_QUOTA_BACKEND_BYTES=8589934592
ETCD_AUTO_COMPACTION_RETENTION=1
```

OS info

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide more context about how etcd is being used.

Comment: Please consider "tightening" the tags that you're using.... `etcd` is important but `ubuntu`, `google-cloud-platform` etc. are likely over broad. The intent is to "advertize" your question to the most likely group (tag) of readers.